# Laravel: Column not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am trying to set up the following SQL in Laravel.

```
$projects = DB::table(DB::raw('places, areas, areas_places'))
    ->select('projects.*')->distinct()
    ->leftJoin('tags_places as r', 'r.place_id', '=', 'places.place_id')
    ->leftjoin('tags as t', 't.id', '=', 'r.tag_id')
    ->join('areas_places as e', 'e.place_id', '=', 'places.place_id')
    ->join('areas as a', 'a.area_id', '=', 'e.area_id')
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'places.place_id' in 'on clause'

The column exists in the database. I've also checked to see if the column is spelled correctly-- it is. So what could I be missing? I am using Laravel Mix version 4.0.7

Comment: Look at the code you posted.  Particularly this line: `->leftJoin('tags_places as r', 'r.place_id', '=', 'place.place_id')` <-- this says `place.place_id`, not `places.place_id`. Maybe your error is just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That was just a typo I made on StackOverflow. The code has been corrected in my post to reflect the actual code. However, I still have the error.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using relations ?

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly? You can output the sql with `toSql()`

Comment: Thank you for your help, @IGP. Using `toSql()` helped me realize that I didn't need `DB::raw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I just didn't need the `DB::raw` statement. This works as expected without problems:

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
    ->select('projects.*')->distinct()
    ->leftJoin('tags_places as r', 'r.place_id', '=', 'places.place_id')
    ->leftjoin('tags as t', 't.id', '=', 'r.tag_id')
    ->join('areas_places as e', 'e.place_id', '=', 'places.place_id')
    ->join('areas as a', 'a.area_id', '=', 'e.area_id')
```

IGP's suggestion to check with `toSql()` was helpful in figuring this out.